# File Name Has "[]" issue

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to activate the browse file. However, when the file name has a "[]" it has an error "Subscript out of range". I would like to recognize the "[]" to activate the file. I will copy the whole data on the file, that's why I will activate it. But, when I'm trying to manually remove the "[]" in the file name, it works successfully. Thanks for the help !

Here is my code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Dim shtName As String
    
    'select folder
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
NextCode:
        'Get the path
    GetFolder = sItem 

    Set fldr = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Check if exist the word in file name
     wrd = "AS"
     'get the file associated with wrd
     strfile = Dir(GetFolder & "\*" & wrd & "*.xl*")
     
     fc = 0
    Do While Len(strfile) > 0
    On Error GoTo endhere
        fc = fc + 1
       
       'open the file
     Workbooks.Open (GetFolder & "\" & strfile)
     Workbooks(strfile).Activate
    

here:
       Workbooks(strfile).Close False
        strfile = Dir
    Loop
   
   
 
endhere:
Debug.Print Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have a dialog for the user to select a folder then don't use what they've selected?

Comment: Try add cmd : [ copy file, rename (replace "[]" with "_" >  process the copied&renamed file via vba > delete the temporary file ]

Comment: I can use that code to open files with [] in the name without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   Dim strFile1 as String
   If InStr(strfile, "[") > 0 Then
        strFile1 = Replace(Replace(strfile, "[", ""), "]", "")
        Name GetFolder & "\" & strfile As GetFolder & "\" & strFile1
        Workbooks.Open (GetFolder & "\" & strFile1)
    Else
        Workbooks.Open (GetFolder & "\" & strfile)
    End If
```

If the characters to be removed do not belong to the file name, belonging to the path, please use the next way:

```
    Dim strFile1 As String
    If InStr(GetFolder & "\" & strfile, "[") > 0 Then
        strFile1 = Replace(Replace(GetFolder & "\" & strfile, "[", ""), "]", "")
        Name GetFolder & "\" & strfile As strFile1
        Workbooks.Open (strFile1)
    Else
        Workbooks.Open (GetFolder & "\" & strfile)
    End If
```

Anyhow, this second version can be use for both cases...

Comment: I already tried this one. However, since I removed the "[]"  I was not able to open the file since the file name has "[]".

Comment: What did you mean by "when I'm trying to remove the "[]", it works successfully"?

Comment: I manually remove it to the file name. Therefore, the file name has no "[]" when I'm browsing it.

Comment: OK. I will adapt the code to change the file name...

Comment: @Elena  Please, try the updated code. It will change the file name...

Comment: @Elena Now, when you say "file name", do you really mean the file name? Or the file full name, meaning that the characters to be removed could be used for a folder?

Comment: Noted on this. Thanks again! :0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is Excel-Version dependent, for me it gives no error. I can open the file and access it with the name that the `Dir` returned, even if the `Name`-property of the workbook replaces the the square brackets with round one (interesting, didn't know that).

However, much more important is that you neither need to `Activate` the workbook nor use the name to open and close it. `Workbooks.Open` is a Function that returns a reference to the opened Workbook, so you should use that:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open (GetFolder & "\" & strfile)
' (...) do your stuff using wb, eg copy a Worksheet:    
wb.Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
wb.Close False
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help :)